# Firebase realtime database unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

My firebase realtime database is not working in my  unity application after implementing app check. Before firebase app check feature it's totally work fine. But now when I try to save my data it denied my database request, and when I monitor my realtime database in app check monitor it shows my request has not contains a app check token:

> this is probably because you are using old firebase SDK in which app check is inside the application

I have updated my firebase SDK to latest version 7.2 for unity, but it still shows the same error. I don't understand what I can do to get app check token in unity.

Answer (score 1):

The App Check is still in Beta and only supports native Android, iOS, and web. You will have to wait until AppCheck has matured enough for the Unity Environment which itself is in late Beta.

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it...can you tell me if there is any way to disable the firebase app check for unity so my application will start working again.

Comment: You can disable enforcement in the console. See the `Unenforce` button here in this video: https://youtu.be/Fjj4fmr2t04?t=696